# ASP.NET Session Timeout Detection Code Not Working in Chrome

Tags: asp.net, session, session-timeout

I have the following 'cookie-cutter' code used and shown often as a way to detect if the Session has timed out in ASP.NET web forms:

```
if (HttpContext.Current != null)
{
    if (Context.Session != null)
    {
        if (Session.IsNewSession)
        {
            string cookieHeader = Request.Headers["Cookie"];
            if ((cookieHeader != null) && cookieHeader.IndexOf("ASP.NET_SessionId", StringComparison.Ordinal) >= 0)
            {
                Redirect the timed out user to the ErrorInfo page:
                Response.Redirect(@"~\ErrorInfo.aspx", true);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

This works perfectly in `Internet Explorer` but not in other browsers like `Chrome`. The issue is that `Request.Headers["Cookie"]` is `null` on application load for `IE` which allows the logic to work, but is already populated for `Chrome`. Therefore when I launch the application in Chrome it immediately redirects to the `ErrorPage` saying the session had timed out.

Does anyone know of a way to modify this code to be more browser agnostic so that I can detect session timeout regardless of the browser?

**EDIT:** I have read this ([ASP.Net Session Timeout detection: Is Session.IsNewSession and SessionCookie detection the best way to do this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/427264/asp-net-session-timeout-detection-is-session-isnewsession-and-sessioncookie-det)) and it does **NOT** offer a specific solution but rather a high level description which is directed to a slightly different use case. I see this asked a lot and there is no concrete solution. This one as well ([Session in ASP.Net(C#) in Firefox and Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10331678/session-in-asp-netc-in-firefox-and-chrome)) is for a different use case and it's solutions do not change the outcome.

Comment: See answer for [ASP.Net Session Timeout detection: Is Session.IsNewSession and SessionCookie detection the best way to do this?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/427264/asp-net-session-timeout-detection-is-session-isnewsession-and-sessioncookie-det).

Comment: I may be totally off with my idea, but since the timeout time is known, wouldn't a user's session have been gone after it timed out? You could catch the [End](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.sessionstatemodule.end.aspx) event of the session or something...

Comment: @KarlAnderson - I read that post yesterday when trying to debug this and the solution really offered a description rather than a hard solution. I also am not working with user's logging out so I don't need that to play into this either.

Comment: @Renan - Session_End firing is not always reliable and it also is raised on the server. http://forums.asp.net/t/1191570.aspx I will be on the server, but need to check on postback.